# How can I link_to edit a specific post, using its id? I need to hardwire the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want any user to edit a question for a specific post. I'm not looping the posts on this page, so I have to hardwire the post_id as the param.
This is what I tried:

```
<%= link_to "Add a question", edit_post_path(@post[:id => 3]) %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Add a question", edit_post_path(@post.3) %>
```

and

```
..., edit_post_path(@post.params[:id == 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails is tricky and helpful. When you pass the object to `posts_path`, all it does is pull the ID out of the object.

So if the ID of the record in `@post` is 2, then these three lines will all do the same thing:

```
posts_path(@post)
posts_path(@post.id)
posts_path(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried this and it worked. I don't know if it's really the Rails way.

```
<%= link_to "Add a question", edit_post_path(@post=Post.find(3)) %>
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: This is a *very* bad idea to do so. Simply say `edit_post_path(@post)` or `edit_post_path(@post.id)` (that's an overkill though). If the `id` is always `3`, then `edit_post_path(3)`.

Comment: `@post=Post.find(3)` is not the right way as the id is hardcoded. And you'll not be knowing the id for your post dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `@post` to the path, provided `@post` is initialized in your controller.

```
<%= link_to "Add a question", edit_post_path(@post) %>
```

**Update:**

If you have `@posts` defined, and it contains all the posts, and you're iterating through it to show individual posts, and I'm assuming you're doing something like this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post">
    <h3><%= post.title %></h3>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
    <!-- You'll pass local post variable to it. to get the link -->
    <%= link_to "Add a question", edit_post_path(post) %>  
  </div>

<% end %>
```

you'll still have access to the individual posts and their ids. So you can easily create the link for adding a new question to it.

Comment: This works only when there's scope to the post. Since I am referring to five different specific posts on the index page, I didn't have such scope.

Comment: Do you have `@posts` variable initialized in your controller which holds all the posts?